# I want to add new role as ROLE_PUBLISHER which only have access to one action in symfony

Tags: symfony, user-roles

In my `security.yml` I added the role `ROLE_PUBLISHER`. I set it up so that `ROLE_USER` inherits the `ROLE_PUBLISHER`:

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_USER:   ROLE_PUBLISHER
```

Controller code as follows.

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}", requirements={"id" = "\d+"}, name="note_update", options={"expose"=true})

 * @Method("PUT")
 * @Secure(roles="ROLE_PUBLISHER")
 *
 * @param $id
 *
 * @return Response|JsonResponse
 */
public function updateAction($id)
{
    // Some code...
}
```

But when I login as `ROLE_PUBLISHER`, I will also have access to `ROLE_USER` actions. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Can you paste your entire security.yml ?

Comment: If you are using FOSUserBundle then all users get ROLE_USER by default https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/1.2.x/Model/User.php

Answer (score 0):

No need to define the ROLE_PUBLISHER role in your security.yml since you don't want any role hierarchy. Roles (prefixed with ROLE_) can be used and invented on the fly and don't need to be defined anywhere.

See the [Roles section](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#roles) of the Symfony2 documentation.

Further: in your security example you defined ROLE_USER to inherit the role ROLE_PUBLISHER and not vice versa. Make sure the logged-in user only has the role ROLE_PUBLISHER.